# What are the "paragraph macros" in :help paragraphs

Tags: vim, vi

Running `:help paragraph` in vim gives:

> A paragraph begins after each empty line, and also at each of a set of
>   paragraph macros, specified by the pairs of characters in the 'paragraphs'
>   option.  The default is "IPLPPPQPP TPHPLIPpLpItpplpipbp", which corresponds to
>   the macros ".IP", ".LP", etc.  (These are nroff macros, so the dot must be in
>   the first column).

Most of the vim help I've seen has been super helpful, and I was beginning to feel I was getting a grip on it. Suddenly though:

> IPLPPPQPP TPHPLIPpLpItpplpipbp

Aaand I'm lost.

Could someone explain to me what this sequence of characters is supposed to mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`nroff(1)` is a unix text-formatting utility. It's e.g. used for formatting the man pages.

In `nroff`, you got macros that do stuff: e.g. `.PP` means following is a paragraph with the first line indented. These macros are usually<sup>(1)</sup> 2-letter codes preceded by a dot.

The docs are saying how Vim detects paragraph boundaries: A paragraph boundary is either an empty new line or a dot in the first column followed by one of the 2-letter codes specified in the `paragraphs` option.

Example:

```
Hello
LP
World
```

If I put the cursor on World and enter `vip` in normal mode. Everything will be selected.

```
Hello
.LP
World
```

`.LP` is contained in the `paragraphs` option, thus `vip` will in this case not mark `Hello` as it's above the paragraph boundary.

---

(1) For 1-letter macros, you append a space. That's why there is a space in the default `paragraphs` value, it's for `.P`.